# What are my options in a .NET DLL hell scenario involving multiple private assemblies with different versions?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly, appdomain

I'm writing a plug-in for a 3rd party application (.NET). This application lets me choose the plug-in (as a .dll library file) to load. However, if I have two versions of the same library---they have the same name but are in different directories---and try to load one after the other, it only loads the first plug-in and treats the second as if it was the first. In other words, if the first plug-in is supposed to show a message box saying "First plug-in" and the second plug-in is supposed to show a message box saying "Second plug-in," then loading the second plug-in *after* the first will actually show a message saying "First plug-in" (i.e., the second plug-in was actually never loaded).

After searching and reading online, I believe that the problem is that the 3rd party application loads its plug-ins into its primary AppDomain. Therefore, plug-in libraries are never unloaded (become *locked*?) and subsequent attempts to load a plug-in with the same name simply uses the library that's already been loaded. I thought perhaps signing my plug-in libraries would fix the problem, but unfortunately, I'm unable to sign them because I depend on a .dll provided by the 3rd party application and it is not signed. Also, I cannot change the 3rd party application's config file, so I cannot play around with probing.

Our current solution is to re-name the assembly for every version of the plug-in library we have (for example, "PlugIn-1.0.dll" and "PlugIn-2.0.dll"), including re-naming all their dependent assemblies. I don't mean just changing their file name, but changing the AssemblyName property and re-compiling. This works, but I'd like to see if there's a cleaner solution. It wouldn't be so bad if it was just the plug-in assembly name we had to change, but we are also forced to change all their dependent .dll's (because different plug-ins may use different versions of these .dll's as well). I tried creating a config file for the plug-in library to change the probing directory, but this doesn't work. It looks like it is the application itself that does the probing, not the library that depends on the .dll's (am I correct in inferring this?)

Finally, I tried having my plug-in create an AppDomain and load its dependent .dll's into it, but unfortunately my plug-in directory location (and dependent .dll's) must be on a remote location relative to the 3rd party app. There are security/permission issues with loading assemblies over network locations in .NET 4.0 (which I'm using) that I haven't been able to solve.

What are my options? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an overview of *everything* you could possibly do wrong.   You'll have to pick up the phone and be assertive with your partner companies.  Accepting sloppy practices just digs you a hole like this.

Comment: @HansPassant, I agree! And I did ask them to sign their assemblies so I could sign mine. They said it's something they're looking into, but I'm guessing it won't happen any time soon.

Comment: It is completely trivial, takes 10 seconds to setup.  Be assertive.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're knocking on the right door with spinning up your own AppDomain. That is the only way I know of to have different versions of the same assembly loaded into the same process.

And yes - as soon as a .NET appdomain has loaded an assembly, it will not load another version of that assembly. Whoever is first wins. And of course, there is no way to unload an assembly once it has been loaded.

As for your permission issues.. Can you copy the assemblies from that network location to a user folder (where the user has write permissions) and load them from there? I've been able to do this successfully for an auto-updating application.

Comment: Great idea. I'll try copying the assemblies to a local location.